# SQL Query -Without using nested subqueries

Tags: sql

**Table1**

```
ID  SystemID    Description
---------------------------
1   25             Test1
1   25             Test2
2   40             Test1
2   40             Test3
3   26             Test9
3   36             Test5
4   70             Test2
4   70             Test9
```

**Table2**

```
ID  Department 
------------------
1   Sales
2   Marketing
3   Accounting
4   Purchasing
```

I have these 2 tables, `Table1` and `Table2`.

I need to select all the distinct ids from `Table1` that have the same description as ID = 1 and SystemID = 25, and then select all the rows from Table2 from the query result.

Is there a better way to query for this, without using nested subqueries?

```
select * 
from Table2 
where ID in (select distinct(ID) 
             from Table1 
             where SystemID = 25
               and Description in (select Description 
                                   from Table1 
                                   where ID = 1 and SystemID = 25))
```

Final output is

```
1 Sales
2 Marketing
4 Purchasing
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: depends on your definition of "better"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I *believe* this should give you the same result. Instead of using an `IN` I used an `EXISTS` and then instead of a futher subquery you can then use a `JOIN`:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table2 T2
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM Table1 T1
                   JOIN Table1 T1t ON T1.[Description] = T1t.[Description]
              WHERE T1.ID = T2.ID
                AND T1t.ID = 1 AND T1t.SystemID = 25);
```

Comment: The results were perfect.Thank you.

Comment: Would love to hear from the downvoter that emerged on this answer 18 months later. Why was this answer not useful to you?

Answer (score 1):

I think you want:

```
select t1.id, t2.department
from table1 t1 join
     table2 t2
     on t1.id = t2.id
where t1.description in (select tt1.description from table1 tt1 where tt1.id = 1 and tt1.systemid = 25);
```

This is standard SQL and should work in both SQL Server and Oracle.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a modification of an outer join to detect presence of a value.

```
SELECT DISTINCT t2.ID, t2.DEPARTMENT
FROM
    table2 AS t2
    INNER JOIN table1 AS t1a ON table2.ID = table1.ID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN table1 AS t1b ON t1b.id = 1 AND t1b.systemID = 25 AND t1b.description = t1a.description
WHERE t1b.ID IS NOT NULL
      AND t1a.systemID = 25
```

This will filter out all entries who don't have a description matching an entry with id 1 and systemID 25

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT T2.* --Use a distinct for simplicity but a group by is better
FROM Table2 AS T2
INNER JOIN Table1 AS T1_Source ON T1_Source.SystemID = 25 AND T1_Source.ID = 1 
/*^ Find table1 with System and ID 
    Expected Result 
    ID  SystemID    Description
    1   25             Test1
    1   25             Test2

    Note Rows are duplicated use distinct or group by
*/
INNER JOIN Table1 AS T1_Target ON T1_Target.Description = T1_Source.Description
/*^ Find table1 with all the Description matching the result we found
    Expected Result 
    ID  SystemID    Description
    1   25             Test1
    1   25             Test2
    2   40             Test1
    4   70             Test2

     Note Rows are duplicated use distinct or group by
*/
```

Comment: I have marked the query that worked.Thank you for your help